# lock CGRect to current position – Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, quartz-2d

I have a `UIButton` that when pressed, changes a Boolean (touchHasBegan2) to YES. And in a `drawRect` method a `CGRect` is drawn when the button is pressed. I want to "lock" the rect to its current location in the view. So when the button is clicked again a new rect is drawn. This is my code:

```
if (touchHasBegan2)
{
    addedLine = CGRectMake(pointWhereUserClicksX, pointWhereUserClicksY, 80, 20);
    CGContextAddRect(context, addedLine);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
}
```

How can I "lock" the rect's location and draw a new one when button is clicked the 2nd time, 3rd time and so on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to keep an array of rectangles.  Each time the button is tapped, add a new rectangle to the end of the array.  In your `drawRect:`, draw every rectangle in the array.

You will probably want to use `+[NSValue valueWithCGRect:]` and `-[NSValue CGRectValue]` to store the rectangles in an `NSMutableArray`.